# How to extract images from an .xml and .img files

Tags: xml, image

Please can someone help me with this problem i have been struggling with for some time now.

I have two files which are .xml and .img. The XML files contains the offsets for the various images and the .img contains the images.

Can someone please help me with a sample code or idea on as to how to extract individual images from the .IMG using the offsets in the XML file.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not teachers, and we are not coders-for-hire. YOU write some code, and maybe we'll try help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed us the XML file and how the offsets look and whether they are in bytes, or metres :-) and whether the length of the binary data is specified. However, assuming the byte offset is 87 bytes, you could do this with `dd`:

```
dd if=file.img of=image.jpg bs=1 iseek=87
```

that will set the blocksize to 1 byte and seek 87 bytes before reading the remainder of the file and storing it in file image.jpg.

The image will probably have superfluous data at at the end if you do not specify a length but many editors will ignore it - including Photoshop. If you do have a length in your XML file, you can add `count=43` if the length is 43 bytes, for example like this:

```
dd if=file.img of=image.jpg bs=1 iseek=87 count=43
```